# generate CRUD methods automatically with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, crud

I am working on a C# application and implement Linq-To-Sql.

For most tables, I just need common CRUD methods (create, read, update, delete). So I was wondering if there is a way to generate them in visual studio?

I can create them myself, but I'll earn a lot of time if they can be auto-generated. I have done it with Symfony, so why not with .Net.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking because the whole point of Linq2Sql is to generate entities and methods to work with this entities, (query, update, delete, etc.).  What in Linq2Sql isn't doing what you want?

Comment: You need to understand that LINQ is a query language. You use it to query data. "Query" is an equivalent of "Read". You don't use LINQ to CREATE, UPDATE or DELETE. Regarding generating CRUD method in general - this is a very bad approach, which leads to writing non-maintainable code. Instead, consider writing a data access layer that would write these methods on the fly. This way if DB structure changes, you will not need to re-generate anything. Benefits add up if you consider deployment effort.

Comment: Use the Repository pattern or change to LINQ-to-EntityFramework. EntityFramework provides a DbContext object with default methods: `All<T>`, `Add<T>`, etc. Its been a while so I don't recall if LINQ-to-SQL provides any sort of DbContext object.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to set up [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907).  Linq-to-SQL is really for just doing simple queries w/ a 1-1 relationship model.  It's not a full ORM.  The type of library you're looking for is known as an ORM, or Object Relationship Mapper, which is used to perform CRUD operations on objects instead of manually writing SQL. Entity Framework would allow you to write linq queries for reads as well.

Comment: To  Peter Ritchie : Linq do exactly what i want, but i have some really simple request to do and i was searching a way to do them automatically for not re-write them each time.

To Neolisk : i use a DAL and a BLL, i wanted  simple CRUD methods for some request in the DAL and manage my data in the BLL. But you are right, i didn't think to the fact that my DB structure can change one day.

To JNYRanger, i'll see to use Entity in my next project. At this point it'll not help me to earn some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to Entity Framework, Visual Studio can create the CRUD logic, classes, and views for you.